# TypeScript files in monorepo is with .js extensions so IDE doesn't understand TypeScript in these files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, webstorm

I've just cloned [React monorepo](https://github.com/facebook/react) and open the folder as a new project in WebStorm IDE. However, for some reason, all .js files in this repo are actually written in TypeScript so the IDE can't figure out the TypeScript written in these files.

For example:

```js
//ReactHooks.js
export function useTransition(): [boolean, (() => void) => void] {
                                 ^Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8010) 
  const dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useTransition();
}
```

I've seen it in some repos, but could never understand how these project configured ther IDE's locally to understand that these files are actually ts files.

I don't know why React team decided to use .js extension for TS files, anyway, how can I configure the IDE to understand that these files are actually TS files?

*(there is no webpack.config at the top level, how do React team actually work on this repo this way?)*

Looked for solution on the web but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's your actual question?

Comment: please see edit @JaredSmith

Comment: It's not Typescript, those are [flow type annotations](https://flow.org/). You might find [this helpful](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/11/using-flow-in-webstorm/)

Comment: Check the second link.

Comment: thank you @JaredSmith, however, this is very strange, why does react team did not do these steps and upload the configurations files to the repo? i cant see `.flowconfig` file. vscode does not recognize these flow annotations either.

Comment: @JaredSmith has provided some helpful links but you should always read the [How to Contribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/how-to-contribute.html) documentation of any repo that has it because it walks you though all this. For example, there is a section on [Flow](https://reactjs.org/docs/codebase-overview.html#flow).

Comment: And perhaps on a more meta level, please understand that any large popular thing is going to have a pretty high bar for understanding the source code: it's almost certainly going to have a complex architecture, complex build pipeline, etc. and the documentation can only sugar coat it just so much. For example if you look up a beginners guide to contributing to the Linux kernel (if there is such a thing) then it is almost certainly going to *start* by assuming that you're already an *expert* C coder, it's not going to explain how to wrangle header files or what valgrind is.

Comment: thank you @JaredSmith you can write your comments as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't Typescript type annotations, they're [flow type annotations](https://flow.org/), and they go in plain .js files.

As for integrating them with Webstorm, [here's a post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/11/using-flow-in-webstorm/) by JetBrains (makers of that IDE) on how to do so.

And perhaps on a more meta level, please understand that any large popular thing is going to have a pretty high bar for understanding the source code: it's almost certainly going to have a complex architecture, complex build pipeline, etc. and the documentation can only sugar coat it just so much. For example if you look up a beginners guide to contributing to the Linux kernel (if there is such a thing) then it is almost certainly going to *start* by assuming that you're already an *expert* C coder, it's not going to explain how to wrangle header files or what valgrind is, or how hardware interrupts work, etc.

Or to put the same point more colloquially:

[image]

Comment: by the way, [got what i wanted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68930011/react-accessing-internal-operation-queue-of-react). so one can simply walk into React code base(after wasting too many hours) @Jared

Comment: @EliavLouski wouldn't call that "simply" lol but I'm glad you got what you needed! Just don't put that into production...